# The relevance of Pappus' and Desargues' theorems

Tags: geometry, reference-request, soft-question, projective-geometry, projective-space

[Pappus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_hexagon_theorem)' and [Desargues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27s_theorem)' theorems are two notable theorems in projective/affine geometry.

I am trying to understand their relevance and significance in the context of (projective) geometry. Specifically, I fail to see the big picture: what is so important about a certain number of straight lines intersecting at a certain number of points?

I would appreciate some intuitive explanation and a broader context in which these theorems are as important as, e.g., Pythagorean theorem in Euclidean geometry.

Comment: An abstract projective plane $P$ can be coordinatized by some division ring $D$ (i.e., $P$ is isomorphic to the standard projective plane defined by means of homogeneous coordinates from $D$) if and only if Desargues's theorem holds in $P$. Furthermore, $D$ is commutative (i.e., it's a field) if and only if Pappus's theorem holds in $P$.

Comment: Richter-Gebert gives many examples in his *Perspectives on Projective Geometry* of how these theorems or variants of them keep cropping up in projective geometry.

Comment: Starting from Euclid's axioms, one can use geometry to define real numbers and to define addition and multiplication. The proof of the commutative law of multiplication is an application of Pappus' theorem, and the proof of the associative law of multiplication is an application of Desargues' theorem.

Comment: @Lee Mosher Could you please provide some good to read reference on the subject?

Comment: I learned about this in Stillwell's book "The Four Pillars of Geometry". Probably there's better references in the literature on projective geometries, but I do not know that literature.